# Is the concept of the integral Images implemented in opencv with java API?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, gaussian

I am doing intensive computation on frames retrieved from a web cam, and these computations makes the programm really slow. so after making research, i found that there is something called `Integral Images`, and i learned about it from [this tutorial](https://computersciencesource.wordpress.com/2010/09/03/computer-vision-the-integral-image/).

now my question is, is the concept of the `Integral Images` implemented in opencv or any other library or I have to develop the concept of `Integral images` by myself? please advise.

Comment: sure : http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#integral(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat)

Comment: just out of curiosity: what are you trying t do ?

Comment: @berak i am trying to implement the center-surround mechanism used in detetcting the salient regions in an image

Answer (score 0):

Yes it exists in openCV

please refer to the question below:
It has a link to the documentation as well as some explanations of how and why it is implemented

[why the integral-image contains extra row and column of zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195420/why-the-integral-image-contains-extra-row-and-column-of-zeros)